# Allowed HTML 4.01 id values regex

Tags: regex, attributes, w3c

Can you help me to build a regex that matches a valid W3C HTML 4.01 `id` value?

According with W3C specs:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: @RohitJain: This, for example: `/^[:_A-Za-z][-.:_A-Za-z0-9]*/`, but even not match a simple string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w:.-]*$
```

`^` depicts the start of string

`[a-zA-Z]` matches an uppercase **or** lowercase letter

`*` matches the preceding character 1 to many times

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

`$` is the end of string

Comment: JSLint does not like the unescaped minus sign. For JSLint it has to be `^[a-zA-Z][\w:.\-]*$`