# regular expression to match an HTML id

Tags: c#, javascript, html, regex

Hi I need a little help to validate a html  id  but the below is not 100% correct

here is what I have  `[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*`

example of my possible html id's

```
test-1

t3__-6
```

Thanks

Comment: show some example of html id?

Comment: What do you mean by - `Validate a HTML ID`?

Comment: html id means..DOM element id, like (#id)...?

Comment: `[A-Za-z]` can also be written as `[A-z]` and `[A-Za-z0-9]` can be written as `[\w]`.

Comment: I don't see why you have both c# and javascript tags. In what language are you doing the validation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this will work.it will validate an ID/NAME token.

```
 ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_:\.-]*
```

Comment: is there an easy way to test it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're speaking of HTML5 id, then the requirement is

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

Which gives this regex :

```
^[\S]+$
```

If you're speaking of HTML4 (don't see why but well) then I guess it's a duplicate. See [Allowed HTML 4.01 id values regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664860/allowed-html-4-01-id-values-regex)

Comment: @DreamEater Hum... yes... I'll change it.

Comment: Tests true for an id like `test-@$@#$"""""'`.